# Driving ATG with Fitnesse?

Tags: fitnesse, atg

Currently working as a coach in an ATG shop and would like to introduce some form of customer acceptance testing. My weapon of choice is usually Fitnesse but the guys here say it's not possible to drive ATG with Fitnesse. I wonder if anyone else has tried this and, if so, what their experiences were?
Thanks in advance - davep

Comment: Are you talking about code-level testing, or web UI testing?

Comment: Have these guys offered any explanation of why "it's not possible to drive ATG with Fitnesse"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're talking about UI testing, rather than code-level testing; "customer acceptance testing" to me implies UI.

I work on ATG,and i use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) to do UI testing, with tests written with JUnit that use those frameworks directly. Our QA guys use [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/w/).

I've never used Fitnesse. However, following a quick look at it, i don't see any showstoppers. You'd want to write fixtures that used HtmlUnit or WebDriver (i'd recommend WebDriver) to hit the site and do things in the fixture methods. This would involve three running processes: the Fitnesse server, a process running the fixtures, and then ATG itself. I wouldn't try to run the fixtures inside ATG. Not for UI testing.

Is that the sort of thing you were thinking of?

Comment: Thanks Tom, that's very useful but we are already using Selenium to hit the site through the UI and I was thinking more about testing at a lightly lower level. In MVC I'd be looking at driving it at the Controller level or maybe through the service layer. Is that possible with ATG?

Comment: That is tougher. ATG code - out of the box and written by your project - has a lot of coupling with the web framework that is hard to mock. I'll see if i can write another answer about that this evening. There are a lot of interesting ideas, but i don't think anyone's really cracked it.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I appreciate your efforts

Comment: 'This evening' obviously didn't happen, but this is a question i'd like to return to. It's an interesting problem, and it's one where i could really use an answer myself.

Comment: No worries, Tom. 
I've also been looking at ATG Dust and DDT too and my thinking is that if these guys can drive ATG with JUnit or DDT unit, why can't we drive ATG with Fitnesse? Although I've used Fitnesse many times in the past, I have to say I'm not an ATG (or eevn Java) expert and my colleagues aren't too familiar with this type of testing. I like to use Fitnesse because of the collaboration aspects of the tool. Essential in a distributed organisation I think.

Comment: Dust is definitely something to look at. I'm not sure what DDTUnit brings to the party. In terms of Fitnesse, i think you might want to create a SLIM server that sits inside a running ATG instance and pushes requests down the servlet pipeline to a JSP which runs a droplet to kick the fixtures off (which could then do things like poke values into form handlers, talk to services, etc). You could shortcut the request pipeline and go straight to services, but lots of important stuff happens in that pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way would be to expose an API (e.g. REST+JSON web services) from ATG, and use Fitnesse to drive that.

This has the advantage of, not only being easier to test, but also supporting responsive HTML 5 and native mobile applications.

Depending on your version of ATG, there are various mechanisms in place to expose a component as a REST service. Better yet, though, take a look at Mobile Cube (http://www.deliverycube.com) as a framework that can be used to build a REST API on ATG. (full disclosure, I designed the framework)

Answer (score 0):

In my current project we are using FitNesse to test application, that use ATG.

We use dyn admin injection fixture for preparing test data (for example,  to creates a web user).
And than we use steps according to  a usual test scenario.